# Fixed button at bottom with RecyclerView and CollapsingToolbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to keep a button fixed at bottom when user's scrolling a RecyclerView. This is what I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AddProduct">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/product_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="teste"
                    android:textColor="#161616"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/rv_test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_product_add_product"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="138dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Test button"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

And then I used [AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener) to adjust button margin according by user scrolling.

It worked, but if user scroll a little fast, it can't adjust the margin very well and the button don't appear to be fixed. It's not reliable.

So, how is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use a `ConstraintLayout` instead of your `RelativeLayout` as below:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/rv_test"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_product_add_product"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_product_add_product"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Test button"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @guillaume, but it didn't work. It produces the same effect as RelativeLayout. I tried to put RecyclerView outside from layout but it overlaps the button.

Comment: I got it.. I had to do a little different but it's working. Thank you to open my eyes :)

Comment: If you figured it out - please take the time to post what worked.

Comment: I tried pretty much the same thing, and adding  android:focusable="true" to the button fixed the issue.